# Unable loading the UI @ localhost:8080/pcori

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to run my application using the above link but I am getting the Error with below stack trace:

Error Log:

```
Context Path:/pcori
Servlet Path:/error
Path Info:null
Query String:null
Stack Trace
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/pcori/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:205)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:145)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:106)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:198)
io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:195)
io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:108)
org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:188)
org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:171)
org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:135)
org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

****WebSecurityConfig.java****

package org.google.apple.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;


@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().
//      sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).
//      and().
        authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/app/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/resources/public/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/resources/public/js/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/resources/public/css/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/login/status/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/login/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/facility/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/login/").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic().disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format this question so it's readable. Also read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to intend the code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: Can you post more of your code? @Controller, @Configuration classes . Thanks. Also FYI, you can specify `.antMatchers("/app/**" ,"/resources/public/**" ,"/resources/public/js/**" ,"/resources/public/css/**" ,"/login/**" ,"/api/login/status/**" ,"/api/login/**", "/api/facility/**", "/api/login/").permitAll()`to keep things a little simpler.